# Cumulative with several conditions by date in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, cumulative-sum

I need to do running total for the quantity of sales in the `sales` table of each category, sub_category1, sub_category2 for example below:

| date | category | sub_category1 | sub_category2 | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Laptop | 2 |
| 01-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Desktop | 5 |
| 01-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Accessories | 10 |
| 01-01-2022 | Beauty | Bath and Body | Shampoo | 5 |
| 02-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Laptop | 4 |
| 02-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Accessories | 3 |
| 02-01-2022 | Housing | Kitchen | Applicancies | 1 |
| 12-01-2022 | Beauty | Comestics | Lipstick | 2 |
| 12-01-2022 | Beauty | Bath and Body | Shampoo | 3 |
| 13-01-2022 | Electronic | Heaphones | Earbud headphone | 2 |

I do the running total as below:

```
SELECT
   * EXCEPT(quantity),
   SUM(quantity) OVER (
      PARTITION BY 
         category,
         sub_category1,
         sub_category2
      ORDER BY date) AS running_total_quantity
FROM sales
```

My result should be:

| date | category | sub_category1 | sub_category2 | running_total_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Laptop | 2 |
| 01-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Desktop | 5 |
| 01-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Accessories | 10 |
| 01-01-2022 | Beauty | Bath and Body | Shampoo | 5 |
| 02-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Laptop | 6 |
| 02-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Accessories | 13 |
| 02-01-2022 | Housing | Kitchen | Applicancies | 1 |
| 12-01-2022 | Beauty | Comestics | Lipstick | 2 |
| 12-01-2022 | Beauty | Bath and Body | Shampoo | 8 |
| 13-01-2022 | Electronic | Heaphones | Earbud headphone | 2 |

However when I create bar chart to show sales quantity group by week on metabase, it is nothing for week time from 03 Jan to 09 Jan while my expectation of the table as below:

| date | category | sub_category1 | sub_category2 | running_total_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Laptop | 2 |
| 01-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Desktop | 5 |
| 01-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Accessories | 10 |
| 01-01-2022 | Beauty | Bath and Body | Shampoo | 5 |
| 02-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Laptop | 6 |
| 02-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Desktop | 5 |
| 02-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Accessories | 13 |
| 02-01-2022 | Beauty | Bath and Body | Shampoo | 5 |
| 02-01-2022 | Housing | Kitchen | Applicancies | 1 |
| 03-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Laptop | 6 |
| 03-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Desktop | 5 |
| 03-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Accessories | 13 |
| 03-01-2022 | Beauty | Bath and Body | Shampoo | 5 |
| 03-01-2022 | Housing | Kitchen | Applicancies | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 11-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Laptop | 6 |
| 11-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Desktop | 5 |
| 11-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Accessories | 13 |
| 11-01-2022 | Beauty | Bath and Body | Shampoo | 5 |
| 11-01-2022 | Housing | Kitchen | Applicancies | 1 |
| 12-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Laptop | 6 |
| 12-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Desktop | 5 |
| 12-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Accessories | 13 |
| 12-01-2022 | Beauty | Bath and Body | Shampoo | 8 |
| 12-01-2022 | Housing | Kitchen | Applicancies | 1 |
| 12-01-2022 | Beauty | Comestics | Lipstick | 2 |
| 13-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Laptop | 6 |
| 13-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Desktop | 5 |
| 13-01-2022 | Electronic | Computer | Accessories | 13 |
| 13-01-2022 | Beauty | Bath and Body | Shampoo | 8 |
| 13-01-2022 | Housing | Kitchen | Applicancies | 1 |
| 13-01-2022 | Beauty | Comestics | Lipstick | 2 |
| 13-01-2022 | Electronic | Heaphones | Earbud headphone | 2 |

I used to create a model which generates all date, category, sub_category1 and subcategory2 then using left join to fill in. But the dates, category and so on are going unlimited then it didn't work.

How can I do this?

Comment: What exactly you mean by - it didn’t work?

Comment: Hi, I mean I will have unlimited date, category, sub_category1, sub_category2. Above  is just a sample with several date, category and so on. I generated all date and cross-join with a table to get all category, sub_category1, sub_category2. It takes really long time to run, I wait for 1 hour still not return any.

Comment: I expect to have the table as the last table I provided above, but I still not know how to do it.

Comment: and what was your query that you want to fix/improve?

Comment: I create a table to generate all dates and try to fill all category, sub_category1, sub_category2 into all dates:

```
WITH daily_date AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2022-01-01', CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS date
),
all_category AS (
  SELECT
     category,
     sub_category1,
     sub_category2
FROM table
)
SELECT *
FROM daily_date, table
```

Then I left right the running total in my query above into this.